# Calculate first day and last day of week of current month

Tags: sqlite, datetime, calculator

I want to calculate first date and last date of a week for the current month given current datetime.

For example, 01 December 2017 is first day and 02 December 2017 is last day of week for that week for the month of December. In the same week of year, 26 November 2017 is first day of week and 
30 November 2017 is last day of week for previous month.

So if today is 01 December 2017, I should get 01-02 from current datetime , instead of 26-02 range.

**PS:** I am trying to do this thing in a query of Sqlite. I want to group some values on a weekly basis. The days of the week should belong to current month. Hence this requirement. Till now this is my query.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as Y,
strftime('%d', datetime(createdOn/1000, 'unixepoch'), '-'||strftime('%w', datetime(createdOn/1000, 'unixepoch'))||' day' )
||'-'||
strftime('%d', datetime(createdOn/1000, 'unixepoch'), '+'||(6-strftime('%w', datetime(createdOn/1000, 'unixepoch')))||' day' )                 AS X
FROM my_table
GROUP BY strftime('%d', datetime(createdOn/1000, 'unixepoch'), '-'||strftime('%w', datetime(createdOn/1000, 'unixepoch'))||' day' )
||'-'||
strftime('%d', datetime(createdOn/1000, 'unixepoch'), '+'||(6-strftime('%w', datetime(createdOn/1000, 'unixepoch')))||' day' )
```

How to achieve that; given current datetime.

Comment: Check the month of the calculated first/last day of the week; if wrong, calculate the first/last day of the month instead. Use [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case).

Comment: @CL I have provided my query. Can you suggest something better ?

Comment: @CL I was able to perfect my query. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Common table expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) are useful to hold intermediate results:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT amount, date(createdOn / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS date
  FROM my_table
),
t2 AS (
  SELECT *,
         date(date, 'weekday 6') AS end_of_week,
         date(date, 'weekday 6', '-6 days') AS start_of_week
  FROM t1
),
t3 AS (
  SELECT *,
         strftime('%m', date         ) AS month,
         strftime('%m', start_of_week) AS sowk_month,
         strftime('%m', end_of_week  ) AS eowk_month,
         date(date, 'start of month') AS start_of_month,
         date(date, '+1 month', 'start of month', '-1 day') AS end_of_month
  FROM t2
),
t4 AS (
  SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN sowk_month = month THEN start_of_week
                                      ELSE start_of_month
         END AS week_in_month_start,
         CASE WHEN eowk_month = month THEN end_of_week
                                      ELSE end_of_month
         END AS week_in_month_end
  FROM t3
),
t5 AS (
  SELECT amount,
         week_in_month_start || '-' || week_in_month_end AS week_in_month
  FROM t4
)
SELECT SUM(amount) AS Y,
       week_in_month
FROM t5
GROUP BY week_in_month;
```

Comment: This is much much better answer than my answer. I have deleted my answer.