# How to get the last date of the week in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, datetime

Let's say I have a column with values in the format of a datetime '2021-07-01 00:00:00.000', how do I get the last date of the week (Sunday) for any datetime such as this in sqlite3? The day of the last date of the week is a Sunday.

So the answer for this date would want something like 2021-07-04 or 2021/07/04 (removing the time part) which is the date of the Sunday for the week the date 2021-07-01 is belonging to.

I know how this can be done in sqlserver but I do not know how to do it in sqlite.

Could someone please assist me on this? Let me know if you need more clarification.

Here is my attempt on sqlserver, but i need to get the same result in sqlite

```
SELECT
somedate,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [somedate]), [somedate]),111) AS Last_Date_Of_Week
FROM table
```

apparently i can't do this in sqlite because sqlite does not have an official datetime type.

Comment: 1) Please only tag a single RDBMS -not 3. 2) Please show us your research and attempt and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate first day and last day of week of current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721347/calculate-first-day-and-last-day-of-week-of-current-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) consider Sunday to be the *first* day of the week, and have a `weekday` modifier to advance a given timestamp to the given day of the week (Using 0-based indexing from Sunday). So:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT date('2021-07-01 00:00:00.000', 'weekday 0');
date('2021-07-01 00:00:00.000', 'weekday 0')
--------------------------------------------
2021-07-04
```